# Substitution of comma separated values

Tags: c#, regex

So I have a list of strings that contains comma separated values on each position, like this:

```
AUSTIN,ORL2,ORL6
CHA,INDY
```

And so on. Is there any way using regular expressions to match the values AND replace/reuse the matched value to generate a new string, like this:

```
<a href='details.aspx?location=AUSTIN'>AUSTIN</a>, <a href='details.aspx?location=ORL2'>ORL2</a>, <a href='details.aspx?location=ORL6'>ORL6</a>
<a href='details.aspx?location=CHA'>CHA</a>, <a href='details.aspx?location=INDY'>INDY</a>
```

I am aware that using split(",") and then looping through the resulting array is way easier, but in my particular case, I wonder if it could be possible to just generate the new string without having to split and loop every single list position.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Certainly possible, but likely not going to net you any significant performance gains and it will probably be confusing to the next person that comes across it.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for the job. If you know your data is always as simple as you showed in your question, then do a simple split(","). Otherwise, consider a CSV library such as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader or even the built-in Oledb provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No explicit looping (though no regex)...

```
var list = "AUSTIN,ORL2,ORL6";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",list.Split(',').Select(x=> "<a href='details.aspx?location="+x+"'>"+x+"</a>").ToArray()));
```

//outputs

```
<a href='details.aspx?location=AUSTIN'>AUSTIN</a>,<a href='details.aspx?location=ORL2'>ORL2</a>,<a href='details.aspx?location=ORL6'>ORL6</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ocelot20 said it all.

Nevertheless, here's a quick program that uses a regular expression:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\w+";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        string sentence = "AUSTIN,ORL2,ORL6\nCHA,INDY";

        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(sentence))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("<a href='details.aspx?location={0}'>{0}</a>",
                              match.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
<a href='details.aspx?location=AUSTIN'>AUSTIN</a>
<a href='details.aspx?location=ORL2'>ORL2</a>
<a href='details.aspx?location=ORL6'>ORL6</a>
<a href='details.aspx?location=CHA'>CHA</a>
<a href='details.aspx?location=INDY'>INDY</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
string input = "Austin,Dallas";
string format = "<a href='details.aspx?location=$1'>$1</a>\n";

var newStr = new Regex(@"(\w+),?").Replace(input, format);
```

But as I said before, it'll just be confusing to whoever comes along to see it (you'll also have to come up with a solution for removing the potential trailing newline or comma...)

Edit - Here is the solution I'd actually go with:

```
string input = "Austin,Dallas";
string format = "<a href='details.aspx?location={0}'>{0}</a>";

var formattedList = input.Split(',').Select (i => string.Format(format, i));
string result = string.Join(",", formattedList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it. Regular Expressions are so versatile.

```
List<string> inputs = new List<string>() { "AUSTIN,ORL2,ORL6", "CHA,INDY" };
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (string input in inputs)
{
    List<string> resultComponents = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, "([A-Z0-9]+(?=,)?)"))
    {
        if (match.Success) resultComponents.Add(string.Format("<a href='details.aspx?location={0}'>{0}</a>", match.Value));
    }
    results.Add(string.Join(", ", resultComponents));
}
```

Please note that I was taking your requirements exactly as you requested. Therefore, the output is exactly what you asked for:

```
<a href='details.aspx?location=AUSTIN'>AUSTIN</a>, <a href='details.aspx?location=ORL2'>ORL2</a>, <a href='details.aspx?location=ORL6'>ORL6</a>
<a href='details.aspx?location=CHA'>CHA</a>, <a href='details.aspx?location=INDY'>INDY</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This replace handles the commas by...well leaving them in if they exist.

```
var data = @"AUSTIN,ORL2,ORL6
CHA,INDY";

Console.WriteLine( Regex.Replace(data,
                                 "([^,\r\n]+)(,?)",
                                 "<a href='details.aspx?location=$1'>$1</a>$2"));

/* Output

<a href='details.aspx?location=AUSTIN'>AUSTIN</a>,<a href='details.aspx?location=ORL2'>ORL2</a>,<a href='details.aspx?location=ORL6'>ORL6</a>
<a href='details.aspx?location=CHA'>CHA</a>,<a href='details.aspx?location=INDY'>INDY</a>

*/
```